# How to Block a deployment for a duplicate release artifact in Jfrog Artifactory using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, artifactory

I need to create a script which should block the deployment of a duplicate release artifact. It should basically check for the path (GAV) in already existing release repos and if the path already exist , Then it should block the deployment of that artifact. we need to use this as a plugin in our Artifactory setup . This plugin should be triggered as soon as there is a POST request . is there any API OR any example on how to create this feature using Groovy.

I know that  there is a permission (overwrite/delete) in artifactory , But we have the multi node setup in which we are replicating local repos from one artifactory instance to other instances. So this (overwrite/delete) thing can prevent the duplicate release deployment in the master instance only , not in the slave instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [user-plugin that uses the 'beforeCreate'](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Build) method. In this section check if the GAVC coordinates exist and if so alter the response using the 'altRespons' and cancel the upload.

I don't have a code sample but it should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks Ariel . I wrote the script using the method that you described and it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear that @MohitDhingra. Feel free to mark the answer as resolved and vote up my reply so other users will know it helped you.